# Make SonarQube ignore empty test classes

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

I have multiple production classes "NaiveHandler", "SmartHandler", "AnotherHandler" that implement the same interface "Handler" and share a lot of code. To reduce code duplication, I extracted an abstract class "AbstractHandler" that contains most of the code, and let the sub-classes inherit and reuse it.

Similarly, the test classes "NaiveHandlerTest", "SmartHandlerTest", "AnotherHandlerTest" for those production classes held tons of duplicate test methods. I moved all these @Test-annotated methods and the test setup out into an abstract class called "HandlerTestBase".

```java
abstract class HandlerTestBase {

  protected Handler cut;
  protected SomeDependency x;

  protected abstract Handler getCutInstance(SomeDependency x);

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    x = Mockito.mock(SomeDependency.class);
    cut = getCutInstance(x);
  }

  @Test
  void providesTheRightThing() {
    when(x.getSomeValue()).thenReturn("zzz");
    var result = cut.doSomething("a");
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("b");
  }

  // more tests that verify the shared code in AbstractHandler

}
```

This abstract class cannot (and should not) run on its own. The "~Base" at the end prevents Maven's tools from picking it up and running it. Instead, Maven picks up the individual test classes "NaiveHandlerTest", "SmartHandlerTest", "AnotherHandlerTest", and runs those.

```java
class SmartHandlerTest extends HandlerTestBase {

  @Override
  protected Handler getCustInstance(SomeDependency x) {
    return new SmartHandler(x);
  }

  // here more tests that only relate to SmartHandler, not the shared code, e.g.

  @Test
  void specificClassDoesTheRightThing() {
    when(x.getSomeValue()).thenReturn("12345");
    var result = cut.doSomething("a");
    assertThat(result).isEqualTo("y");
  }

}
```

All of this works beautifully.

As one consequence however, one of the test sub-classes, "NaiveHandlerTest" is now empty. It inherits the tests from the abstract class and runs those, but doesn't add any specific tests of its own. For me, this is not a problem.

```java
class NaiveHandlerTest extends HandlerTestBase {

  @Override
  protected Handler getCustInstance(SomeDependency x) {
    return new NaiveHandler(x);
  }

}
```

However, SonarQube picks out this class and reports the code smell "Add some tests to this class", saying that "There's no point in having a JUnit TestCase without any test methods." For other cases, I would agree, but in this pattern SonarQube does not recognize that the test class may look empty but inherits and runs test methods from its super-class.

I could set this finding to "False Positive" to remove it. I could also annotate the seemingly empty test class with `@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("java:S2187")` to switch off this check here. Is there a still better way to get rid of this finding, such as a tiny tweak to the design that makes SonarQube aware of the existing tests?

Comment: I don't think there's another way short of adding a dummy test: `@Test void makeSonarHappy() { assertTrue(true); }`; but this will likely cause a different Sonar rule to break :)

Comment: if your testclass has nothing to test but what the abstract class does, what actually use does the actual class have?

Comment: @Stultuske The AbstractTestBase cannot instantiate the class under test. It is the sub-class's task to do this. The abstract class offers an `abstract protected Handler getCutInstance();` that the sub-class overwrites with `@Override protected Handler getCutInstance() { return new NaiveHandlerTest(); }`.

Comment: @Florian I'm aware of what an abstract class is. So, you test the functionality of a (specific) child class in a testclass supposedly testing the abstract class?

Comment: @Florian can you show the code for the abstract class and the test? It is (almost) always easier to show code instead of describing code with prose. Show the code and it's immediately clear to everybody what the code is instead of having to guess.

Comment: @Stultuske No, the test class "HandlerTestBase" is designed such that it tests the interface "Handler" itself. It has no direct relation to the abstract class or the specifics of its code. It covers cases that should be identical for all the implementations of "Handler".

Comment: @knittl Added pseudo code. The real code is too lengthy and adds too much noise.